# How to rename file, Java.nio?

Tags: java, nio, file-rename

Got a storage `"client_storage/"`, and I need to rename files in it.

Using `TextInputDialog` to rename.

`TextInputDialog` work fine.

But I've got an `Exception` in `Files.move()` method.

Here is my code:

```
    public void renameFile(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("Rename");
    dialog.setTitle("Rename");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Rename File");
    dialog.setContentText("New name");
    Optional<String> res = dialog.showAndWait();

    if (res.isPresent()) {
        try {
            Path paths = Paths.get("client_storage/" + ClientListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());
            Files.move(paths, paths.resolve(res.get()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

got an Exception on this line:

```
Files.move(paths, paths.resolve(res.get()), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

what I'am doing wrong?

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: client_storage\[text file.txt];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work like this:

```
 public void renameFile(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("Rename");
    dialog.setTitle("Rename");
    dialog.setHeaderText("Rename File");
    dialog.setContentText("New name");
    Optional<String> res = dialog.showAndWait();
    if (res.isPresent()) {
        try {
            Path paths = Paths.get("client_storage/" + ClientListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            Files.move(paths, paths.resolveSibling(res.get()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ClientListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` returns a list, hence the brackets in the error message.

Comment: String s  = ClientListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();                         result for ListView returns, without brackets

Answer (score 0):

I guess something this

```
 Path paths = Paths.get("client_storage/" + ClientListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems());

 Path paths1 = Paths.get("client_storage/" + newName);

 Files.move(paths, paths1, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```